# Join date/time from two columns in dataframe into one

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, time

I have the following data in two columns that I want to concatenate into a single pandas column:

```
0    2015-08-01   00:00-8:00
```

The format I would like it to be phrased in is:

```
0 2015-08-01T09:00:00-08:00
```

I might have the time wrong on the format I would like it in, but I have tried several to_datetime conversions with no luck.

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: are the original columns strings?

Comment: also what exactly do you want? a new column of datetimes?  if so how do you interpret the column 00:00-8:00 and 09:00:00-08:00? what are the units?

Comment: 0 2015-08-01T09:00:00-08:00 is pulled from some Google python example code for updating a google calendar. I have a feeling that the last 4 digits are hours and minutes

Comment: my original columns are date time objects in pandas

Comment: what happens if you do `type(df.iloc[0][0])` and `type(df.iloc[0][1])` where df is your dataframe and `0` and `1` are your columns ... i dont recognize 00:00-8:00 as a datetime .... also how do you want to combine two datetimes into a single datetime?

Answer (score 1):

Chris,

the easiest way would be to combine each cell with a concatenation formula as follows:

```
new = cell1 + " " + cell2 + " " + cell3
```

but if you are looking to retain date integrity and maybe do some simple calculations... here is my choice method for resolving this problem.

first, I would like to clarify that your date is a time span, but we can do fun things with this as well. 
I have mocked up your data for ease of reference (this is just for display purposes - not actually a matrix)

your data looks like this

```
a    b             c    
0    2015-08-01    00:00-8:00
0    2015-09-03    6:00-17:00
```

notice here that the hour ranges do not have a reliable length, this might not be the case with your data but here is a solution that will work regardless.

```
def combineTime(b,c):
  from datetime import datetime
  dashNum = c.find("-")
  start = (b + " " + c[:dashNum])
  finish = (b + " " + c[dashNum+1:])
  startDate = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  finishDate = datetime.strptime(finish, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  return startDate
```

this, when run, returns the following

```
>>> combineTime(b,c)
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 1, 0, 0)
```

you could just as easily swap return startDat for return finishDate like so

```
def combineTime(b,c):
  from datetime import datetime
  dashNum = c.find("-")
  start = (b + " " + c[:dashNum])
  finish = (b + " " + c[dashNum+1:])
  startDate = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  finishDate = datetime.strptime(finish, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  return finishDate
```

which returns

```
>>> combineTime(b,c)
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 1, 8, 0)
```

you can then do some fun things like determine the length of time between start and finish like so...

```
def elapseTime(b,c):
  from datetime import datetime
  dashNum = c.find("-")
  start = (b + " " + c[:dashNum])
  finish = (b + " " + c[dashNum+1:])
  startDate = datetime.strptime(start, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  finishDate = datetime.strptime(finish, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  timeDiff = finishDate - startDate
  elapHour = timeDiff.total_seconds()/3600
  return round(elapHour, 2)
```

now, you can use these functions to populate new columns with start date, finish date, and elapsed time!